# How to get content from json with SharedPreferences- Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get only `content` from this json:

```
{

    id: 2,
    profileImage: {
        id: 1,
        fileId: "e8ec429d-1e09-48c9-9ec8-6e61c1177324.jpg",
        content: "http://localhost/file/e8ec429d-1e09-48c9-9ec8-6e61c1177324.jpg"
    }
}
```

I want to get him from response after my login request using `sharedpreferences`:

```
  Future<bool> makeLoginRequest(String email, password) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {
      'email': emailController.text,
      'password': passwordController.text
    };
    var jsonResponse;
    var url = 'http://10.0.2.2:80/user/login';
    var response = await http.post(url, body: data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _isLoading = false;
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      setState((){
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NavBar()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the *content* String you can do something like:

```
  String content = jsonResponse['profileImage']['content'];
```

However a couple of recommendations, I would separate the parsing logic from the networking logic and in general try to have Model objects to map the models you receive from your services (network/storage) instead of extracting directly its content. For a trivial use case like this it's fine but for more complex scenarios it will allow you to write cleaner and more testable code.

Comment: thanks but when i use ```sharedPreferences.setString("profileImage", jsonResponse['profileImage']['content']);``` debugger stop me at this error: ```NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: 1
Tried calling: []("content"))```

Comment: Please check you code in case there's some error. I've tried on my machine and this:

```var jsonResponse = json.decode(response);
  String content = jsonResponse['profileImage']['content'];
  sharedPreferences.setString("profileImage", content);```

Works perfectly. Then I can retrieve it with: ```String whateverName = sharedPreferences.getString("profileImage");```

Comment: i don't know why but for me it don't work :/ still this same error, i don't know why ```int``` is in him

Comment: It was an error with my backend, thanks for help :)